# Odoo - Context defined in view not passed in form

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, odoo, odoo-15

I'm using Odoov15, I try to inherit the Odoo `sale_crm` module. To make my tests, I modify the `sale_order_views.xml` in `sale_crm/views`.

I add thoses lines in the `sale_view_inherit123` form :

```
<xpath expr="//field[@name='payment_term_id']" position="after">
     <field name="opportunity_id" help="Log in the chatter from which opportunity the order originates" context="{'default_type': 'opportunity', 'default_phone': 'XX XX XX XX XX'}"/>
</xpath>
```

The code is working as the field is indeed added after the `payment_term_id` field. However, the "Create and Edit" button of the field does not hold any of the default data, the type is still `lead` at creation and no default phone is given.

In debug mode, I can clearly see the context of my field is "Context: {}", so it's like the field is added, but the context is removed in the form.

My goal is to have the opportunity created from the `sale_order` view with `opportunity` as a `type` instead of `lead` when I create it via the many2one field in the `sale_order` form (with create and edit or just create). The "Phone" in the line of code above was just for the test. I'll probably prefill a lot more fields but it would be a good start.

Answer (score 1):

This is because there is a default set on the field level. You are using the default feature that will convert all opportunities in the lead as a step for verification, check this default code

`type = fields.Selection([('lead', 'Lead'), ('opportunity', 'Opportunity')], index=True, required=True, tracking=15,default=lambda self: 'lead' if self.env['res.users'].has_group('crm.group_use_lead') else 'opportunity', help="Type is used to separate Leads and Opportunities")`

To make it work, you will need to override this default.

Debug in compute to check if you have context value there and if yes, the change values accordingly

Comment: Thank you, looks like the answer. However i'm not satisfied with the solution, it means I can't modify the default behavior for my view in `sale` form only and will need to comprise the way crm works just to have a different default value when creating from Many2one?

Comment: Hi, I just checked your context code on demo.odoo.com, and it's working perfectly, which makes my logic wrong, but I did that from the front end on the field already on the sales order under the source document. please check from the front end if your context is added to the field from which you are creating